# How do you access the directory that your module is in?

Tags: node.js

If you have a module that's being imported in some code, let's say...

```
var my_cool_module = require('my_directory/my_cool_module');

my_cool_module.print_directory_name();
```

And I'm in that module's context, say this is the file `my_cool_module.js`...

```
function get_dir_name() {
  // get the directory name...
  return directory_name;
}

exports.module.print_directory_name = function() {
  console.log("This module is in directory " + get_dir_name());
};
```

How can I get the directory that the module is in (i.e. "my_directory")

Answer (score 0):

I found out from the node.js documentation [here](https://nodejs.org/api/modules.html#modules_dirname) that you can use `__dirname`

```
function get_directory_name() {
  return __dirname;
}
```